# Flash AS3 : addChild() does not display imported movieclip

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs3

I fought with the IDE and read around all day enough to learn that in AS3, the exported class name of a lib symbol matters.

I have hello.fla. In it I created a simple textfield with a string ('hello') - coverted it to a symbol (movieclip) and did the following:

- made the classname 'Hello'.
- Export for AS is checked
- Export in first frame is checked.

Once i did all that i nuked the instance on the stage. I thought I might add some extra functionality later so I actually also built a Hello.as class, which extends MovieClip, and which lives in the default pkg* and the whole fla builds fine:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Hello extends MovieClip
    {
        public function Hello()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Now my main.fla, same folder, uses document class Main, and Main.as does the following:

```
private var h:MovieClip;
//...
h = new Hello();
this.addChild(h); //no joy
```

**till i get this working, nothing is in folders: all the files are in the root folder.*

Comment: What do you get if you trace h.parent, h.x, h.y, h.alpha after adding it to the stage?

Comment: I haven't been able to successfully add it to the stage via root or Stage. Only this.addChild compiled. Stage.addChild yields err #1061

Comment: in the root of the .fla, "this" refers to an instance of Stage (which is a class). So `this.addChild(h)` should work

Comment: OK I tried that... and I logged x and y - they are both 0, which seems correct (origin at top left).

Comment: Omigosh... and for some BIZARRE reason, alpha is 1 (one) !!! Why would that be? hmm... will try forcing alpha to 100 and see what happens...

Comment: Ok set alpha to 100, logged it afterwards and it tells me h.alpha is indeed 100, but h IS STILL NOT VISIBLE... :(

Comment: Alpha should be 1, alpha range is [0,1] with 1 being completely visible in AS3.

Comment: Probably the code that creates the new Hello() is never being called, did you try that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### THE SOLUTION

Suppose that the library symbol lives inside an .fla such as Hello.fla:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    /**
     * empty mc (blank stage) with a single library symbol containing whatever the hell you want (eg a shape). with settings:
     * class = Hello <=== this refers to a specific library symbol, not the entire Hello.fla and whatever else is on the stage when you build it.
     * export for AS : checked
     * export for runtime sharing (as Hello.swf) : checked <==== This was the step I'd missed
     * export in 1st frame : checked
     */
    public class Hello extends MovieClip
    {
        public function Hello()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

The main timeline / document class :

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import Hello;

    /**
     * this is the document class.
     */
    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        public function Main()
        {
            this.h = new Hello();
            this.l= new Loader();
            this.l.load( new URLRequest("Hello.swf") );
            this.l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, this.test);
        }

        public function test(e:Event)
        {
            this.h = new Hello();
            h.x = 100;
            h.y = 100;
            this.addChild(this.h); //shows up on stage. Finally!
        }

        private var h:MovieClip;
        private var l:Loader;
    }

}
```

Hope it helps some other newbs like me new to AS3.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this.addChild(h), does it work if you try root.addChild(h)?

Edit: _root -> root for AS3

Comment: Wrong. There is no root in AS3. You can "emulate it", but it not a language magic variable as it used to be.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add it to the stage, ie

```
stage.addChild(h);
```

Comment: well 'stage' did nothing, so I tried 'Stage', and I get access of undefined property Stage. :(

Comment: I also tried import flash.display.Stage, which leads to a different error (#1061 - Call to a possibly undefined method addChild through a reference with static type Class).